# iOS - Check if webView is loaded with PDF content on non-'pdf' file extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I would like to Check (boolean value) if PDF content is loaded in the UIWebView. This question already exists, but not this case.

It's not as simple as just checking the path extension of the webView Url because this PDF content is generated via ASPX. The extension will return 'aspx'. Also not just looking in the url, the string 'pdf' will always be found in the url since I requesting a PDF file. I need to check if the server really returns a PDF file as it should.

Ok, The webView is loaded with PDF content but not to a specific pdf file on the server. (maybe apache redirect,aspx pdf generation or just something else)

If this url is loaded in the Safari Application (to the aspx file), it will detect this PDF content (even if aspx file). It says "open in..." and so on.

How to detect if the UIWebView is loaded with PDF content on non-pdf extention file?

Jonathan

Comment: Just a guess, but could you check the MIME?

Comment: I've updated my answer from the other day hopefully this now answers you question and give it an up vote and tick for being right.

Comment: @iosDevSi Your answer is not here anymore, I can't see it. This question?

Comment: Realised you wanted to use a web view my answer wasn't so I deleted it as you have the answer for that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it using this:

Thanks @Guilherme

```
-(bool)isPDFContentLoadedInWebView:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *mime =[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:webView.request].response.MIMEType;
    if (!([mime rangeOfString:@"pdf"].location == 0)) {
    return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }

    return NO;
}
```